# Difference between Year and yearForWeekOfYear - iOS (NSDateComponents)

Tags: ios, nsdatecomponents

While working on NSDateComponents I come to know one property which I have never used.

I have try to look in apple document as well but didn't get proper answer.
Apple says,

```
Declaration
OBJECTIVE-C

    @property NSInteger yearForWeekOfYear

Discussion

This value is interpreted in the context of the calendar with which it is used
```

Does anybody knows exactly what this property do ?
e.g.

```
- Year property will return year value.
- Day property will rerun day value
- MonthOfYear property will return month number of particular year
- WeekOfYear will return Week number of particular year
- yearForWeekOfYear will return ????? (Can anybody give simple example as well so I can easily understand )
```

Answer (score 1):

`yearForWeekOfYear` are based off of something called the ISO Week Date, which is part of the ISO 8601 standard.  You can read more about it on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).  The 52nd week of the year as we normally use it may not be the 52nd week according to the `weekOfYear` property, depending on which year you are in, and what day of the week the year starts on in the normal Gregorian calendar (as opposed to the ISO Week Date version of the Gregorian Calendar).

Comment: That means If 2015 has 53 week than yearforweekofyear:53-2015 will return 2016... Got your point. Thanks buddy.